# Add font awsome icon to a Javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, twitter-bootstrap, icons

I have this script that keeps changing the webpage title.

```
<script>
        var titleArray = ["AAAAA","BBBBB","CCCCC","DDDDD","EEEEE","FFFFF","GGGGG","HHHHH","IIIII","JJJJJ"];
        var N = titleArray.length;
        var i = 0;
        setInterval(func,500);
        function func(){
            if (i == 10) {
                i = 0;
            }
            document.title = titleArray[i];
            i++;
        }

</script>
```

The titles are in the form of strings but I want to be able to add font icons like google icons, font awesome icons, bootstrap glypicons, or icomoon etc. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you please explain why are you doing like this? we might be able to help you with better suggestion.

Comment: You can't change the font in the title as it's controlled by the browser (font-awesome) and you can't add images as it's text only (glyphs).  You can change the fav icon (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) but if you cange it via a script every 0.5s, I suspect many people will leave your page *very* quickly!

Comment: Mr_Green and freedomn-m.both of you may be right.I just really want do this before deciding if it is bad or good.If changing favicon is the only alternative than I would like to know how to do it.Then if it is bad so i would have learned from my mistake.BUT FIRST THING'S FIRST, how do I do IT???????

Comment: You won't get any help if you use all caps to talk to people, just saying, comes across as very rude.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken what you are asking is possible, try below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link id="ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var titleArray = ["http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico","https://en.wikipedia.org/static/favicon/wikipedia.ico"];
            setInterval(func,500);
            var i=0;
            function func(){
                if (i == 2) {
                    i = 0;
                }
                document.getElementById('ico').href = titleArray[i];
                console.log(titleArray[i]);
                i++;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            func();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```